# WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2397' ('MQRC_JSSE_ERROR') while using jetty config for MQ Connection

Tags: jetty, ibm-mq

I'm configuring MQ connection in jetty-env.xml file as :

```
<New id="myJmsConnection" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg><Ref refid="wac"/></Arg>
    <Arg>jms/mymq</Arg>
    <Arg>
           <New class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory">
                <Set name="connectionNameList">x.x.x.x</Set>
                <Set name="port">xxx</Set>
                <Set name="queueManager">xxx</Set>
                <Set name="channel">xxx.CHANNEL</Set>
                <Set name="transportType">1</Set>
                <Set name="SSLCipherSuite">xxxx</Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
  </New>
```

With the above configuration, when I run jetty I'm getting this error
nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2397' ('MQRC_JSSE_ERROR')

But the same config values when I use in my Code to make MQ connection, I'm able to establish the connection

```
@Bean(name="MQConnectionFactory")
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {

        if (factory == null) {
            factory = new MQConnectionFactory();
            try {
                factory.setConnectionNameList(env.getRequiredProperty(HOST));
                factory.setPort(Integer.parseInt(env.getRequiredProperty(PORT)));            
                factory.setQueueManager(env.getRequiredProperty(QUEUE_MANAGER));
                factory.setChannel(env.getRequiredProperty(CHANNEL));
                factory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
                factory.setSSLCipherSuite(env.getRequiredProperty(SSL_CIPHER_SUITE));
                factory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, env.getRequiredProperty(QUEUE_USERID));
                factory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, env.getRequiredProperty(QUEUE_PASSWORD));

            } catch (JMSException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        return factory;
    }
```

My question is why the connectivity is working from the Java code but it throws MQ exception when configured in jetty-env.xml?

Comment: This suggests that the Jetty environment (which I am not familiar with) does not have the JSSE environment set up correctly. Do you have any additional error information you have not added to your question?

Comment: Please post the full stack from the error.  Are you sure that both your standalone application and jetty have the exact same MQ related jar files in the path?  Which specific version of the MQ jar files are you using?  The version can be obtained with `unzip -p com.ibm.mq.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF|grep -i Implementation-Version` if on a linux system.  What type of JRE is this (ex: IBM, Oracle, OpenJDK).  What specific SSLCipherSuite are you specifying?

Comment: In the event that the full stack does not provide information that helps solve this you can TLS debug information by setting the java system property `javax.net.debug=all` for example adding the following to the java startup command `-Djavax.net.debug=all`.

Comment: There is nothing about https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration in this question. Please, be careful with tags in the future.

Comment: Vishal, do you have any further input to our follow up questions?  Were you able to resolve the issue, if so please post a answer with what the resolution was to help people that run into the same issue in the future.